# error TS6143 при сборке, если добавлен файл .js в папку src

Tags: angular5

При сборке сообщение ERROR in src/app/task/task-list.component.ts(8,25): error TS6143: Module '../shared/config' was resolved to '......./src/app/shared/config.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.
И на 1.6.6 и на 1.7.2.

Как правильно подключить .js файл в таком случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

кэп предполагает: найти файл `tsconfig.json` и в него добавить `"allowJs": true`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавление "allowJs": true решило проблему в проэкте, созданном на cli 1.7.2. А вот внесение данной записи в проэкт созданный на 1.6.6 результата не давал, даже если запускался под 1.7.2. Как то так... Вообщем спасибо!